In linear regression, is it possible to combine coefficients into a single parameter so that a prior can be added
I have model as such:
$$ y=b_0+\beta_1treatment+\beta_2treatment*time $$
I also have an elicited prior of the treatment effect that I want to apply to $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$. As far as I'm aware, I cannot do this in R, but I thought that it might be possible to do this in jags by replacing the two terms on the right have side with a parameter and applying the prior to that parameter, as such:
$$ y=\beta_0+\alpha $$
$$ \alpha = \beta_1treatment+\beta_2treatment*time $$
with the prior:
$$ \alpha ~ N(\mu, \sigma^2) $$
I have tried this in rjags with the edited code below (from here). But I ended up getting an error message. I was wondering, is this error because of the way I have programmed it, or is this mathematically not possible?
library(car)
data(Angell)
angell.1 <- Angell[, -4] ## take off the fourth column (remember, the order is (row, column))
    
angell.model.jags <- function()  {

 for(i in 1:N){
 moral[i]~dnorm(mu[i], tau)
 mu[i]<- alpha + b[i]
 b[i] <- beta1*hetero[i] + beta2*mobility[i]
 }
 
 alpha~dnorm(0, .01)
 beta1~dunif(-100,100)
 beta2~dunif(-100,100)
 tau~dgamma(.01,.01)
 b ~ dnorm(10,2)

}

## Now define the vectors of the data matrix for JAGS:

moral <- angell.1$moral
hetero <- angell.1$hetero
mobility <- angell.1$mobility
N <- length(angell.1$moral)

## Read in the Angell data for JAGS

angell.data  <- list("moral", "hetero", "mobility", "N")
angell.data  <- list(moral = Angell$moral, hetero = Angell$hetero, mobility = Angell$mobility, N = length(Angell$moral))

## Name the parameters of the JAGS model you will monitor

angell.params <- c("alpha", "beta1", "beta2", "b")

## Define the starting values for JAGS


## Alternatively, provide different starting values for each chain:
inits1 <- list("alpha"=0, "beta1"=0, "beta2"=0, "b"=10) 
inits2 <- list("alpha"=1, "beta1"=1, "beta2"=1, "b"=15)
angell.inits <- list(inits1, inits2)

## Fit the model in JAGS, having previously copied the BUGS model into your working directory as "angell.model.jags"

angellfit <- jags(data=angell.data, inits=angell.inits, angell.params, n.chains=2, n.iter=9000, n.burnin=1000, model.file=angell.model.jags)


There are other packages, such as rstanarm or brms that may be easier to use.  Prior specification in rstanarm is a little more restricted than in brms but quite straightforward.  prior <- normal(location=c(0,0,10), scale=c(1,1,1)), for a model with three coefficients (the prior on the intercept is specified in its own parameter), and res <- stan_glm(y~x1+x2+x3, prior=prior, data=dt) , for example.

@jbowman thanks for your response. In stan, is it possible to combine coefficients, such as x1 and x2 (s.t. gamma=x1+x2) and add a prior onto gamma?
